# Excel VBA to open hyperlinks - slowly initially?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, excel-2010

I have copied some VBA code online that opens a set of links from excel into multiple tabs in Internet explorer. The problem is, especially on slower computers, IE takes a little while to open and so the computer just loads up another IE window so you end up having say 3 links in one IE window, and another 7 in another one, it will also occasionally miss out a link altogether.

I therefore slowed down the code by including a 2 second break between each link that is loaded. This has solved the problem - one IE session, all links load up, this problem now is that the wait seems excessive. What I want is to perhaps load the first 2-3 links with the delay and then the remaining can load up as fast as possible (assuming all links do end up loading, without another IE session loading as well..)

How do I do this? - thank you in advance.

Anyway here's the code: ignore the bit at the start and very end, it's just highlighting various links and hiding some columns...:

```
Sub Convert2links()
'
' Convert2links Macro
'

'
Columns("G:L").Select
    Range("G7").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("J8:J28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A8").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, Rng.Value
Next


    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Next
    Columns("H:K").Select
    Range("H7").Activate
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("A8").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some modified code from Ken Puls to check if IE is open

```
Public Function IEIsOpen() As Boolean

 'IMPORTANT:  Requires reference to Microsoft Internet Controls!!
    'Set in Tools --> References --> Microsoft Internet Controls

    Dim shellWins As SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    Dim explorer As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set shellWins = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    For Each explorer In shellWins
        If explorer.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then
            IEIsOpen = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Set shellWins = Nothing
    Set explorer = Nothing

End Function
```

Then you could do something like

```
For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
    xHyperlink.Follow
    Do Until IEIsOpen
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next
```

It'll open the first one, then not open any others until IE is open.

**Update**

You better put some check in there to prevent an endless loop

```
Dim dtStart As Date

dtStart = Now
For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
    xHyperlink.Follow
    Do Until IEIsOpen Or Now - dtStart > TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next xHyperlink
```

Now it will wait for IE or five seconds, whichever comes first.

Comment: it's now missing out on roughly two links (out of about ~10) that I have put in excel. The links that do not load change each time. It's not consistent - its like the computer is lazy and sometimes loads them all sometimes doesn't...